# If $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. r.v.'s, then is it true for any random variable $\theta$ that $P(Y_n|Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n-1}, \theta) = P(Y_n|\theta)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, then is it true for any random variable $\theta$ that:

$$
P(Y_n|Y_1, \ldots, Y_{n-1}, \theta) = P(Y_n|\theta)
$$?

I am unable to see how to deal with the random variable $\theta$, does anyone have any ideas? Is there an assumption here that $\theta$ must be independent of the $Y_i$'s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(Y_n|Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1},\theta) 
=\frac{\mathbb{P}(Y_n,Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1},\theta) }{ \mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1},\theta)} 
=\frac{ \mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}| Y_n,\theta) \mathbb{P}(Y_n,\theta) }{\mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}|\theta) \mathbb{P}(\theta) }
=\frac{ \mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}| Y_n,\theta)  }{\mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}|\theta)}\mathbb{P}(Y_n|\theta)
\end{align}
So the assertion is true iff $\mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}| Y_n,\theta) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}|\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific name for the if and only if condition of $\mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}| Y_n,\theta) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1,\ldots , Y_{n-1}|\theta)$?

Comment: @user321627 Nothing that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

No. A counterexample is
$$
\theta = Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_n
$$